# ¿Cual es la mejor práctica para crear un Index en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy teniendo problemas con el tiempo de respuesta de los queries que voy ejecutando con el SQL Server.

Investigando encontré que una buena práctica es crear índices asociados a los campos dentro de una tabla o de una vista.

**¿Cuál es la mejor forma de crear estos índices?, ¿es conveniente hacer un indice por cada campo o hacer un indice por varios campos?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La cantidad de índices que necesites crear depende mucho de tu aplicación y de las consultas que hagas.

Agregar índices va a hacer que las consultas (SELECT) ejecuten más rápido, pero las actualizaciones a la base de datos (INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE) van a ser más lentas.

Definitivamente no deberías crear un índice para cada campo. Lo que sí deberías hacer es entender cómo funcionan los índices para saber cuáles te conviene crear.

Lo mejor sería que identifiques las consultas que más demoran, y para cada una de ellas decidir si tienes que crear un índice o no, y qué índice crear.

Algunas reglas que deberían ser bastante genéricas sobre qué índice crear (luego de identificada la consulta):

- si la consulta recorre toda la tabla y tiene un ORDER, los campos que están en el ORDER podrían estar en un índice.
- si una tabla tiene muchas columnas, y tu consulta solo opera con unas pocas, poniendo todas las columnas en el índice puede hacer que el SELECT no tenga que ir a la tabla, va directamente al índice
- en una tabla con muchos registros, si la consulta tiene un WHERE que filtra muchos de estos registros, entonces crear un índice por los campos del WHERE puede ser bastante razonable.

En todo caso SQL Server tiene una herramienta, SQL Server Profiler, que puede ayudarte a decidir qué índices pueden servir en tu aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos por tu respuesta sobre el tema. Lo que tengo son vistas que realizan consultas muy elaboradas, conectando varias tablas entre si y me he percatado que esas vistas son las que más demoran, peor aún si son vistas unidas con otras vistas en cascada, en esos caso lo que estoy haciendo es cambiando esas vistas por unas más simples que van directo a las tablas y a los campos necesarios. Como bien dices, de repente podría hacer un indice para los campos principales, los que son usualmente trabajados en las vistas, como es el caso de un maestro. Voy a revisar el Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

A lo que muy bien dijo @Marcos, quería explicarte el tema de los índices de manera muy sencilla.

SQL Server por defecto te crea índices en las tablas usando las Claves Primarias.

Muchas veces es lo que se necesita, pero no siempre es así.

Pensá en una guía telefónica en papel: Está ordenada por **Ciudad, Apellido y Nombre**. Podemos decir que su **índice** son esos campos. Encontrar un número es sencillo así, porque es por lo que generalmente se busca. Si quiero todos los números de la ciudad “A”, es fácil sacarlos.

Ahora **¿Qué pasaría si quisiera todos los números de las personas cuyo nombre es “Juan Manuel”?** Ahora el índice no me serviría de nada. Tendría que recorrer de tapa a tapa para sacarlos todos.

En las bases de datos pasa lo mismo. Es importante que el índice sea por lo que más se busca.

Y un detalle, en SQL Server podes **tener dos tipos** de índices.

- Clúster (Es uno solo, y debería ser el campo/campos por los que más se accede a la tabla)
- Lógicos (Pueden ser varios)

Te animo a que los investigues y veas qué es lo mejor para tu aplicación.

En pocas palabras, como **mal** podría decir que estaría no tener índices o crear índices que no se usan para nada. Como @Marcos te explicó, eso sobrecarga la base de datos con cosas que no se usan.

Lo que nosotros hacemos en mi empresa generalemente es tener un índice lógico por la clave primaria (para los joins). El índice clúster generalmete por un campo de fecha y clave primaria.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Además de lo que te han comentado, yo te recomiendo utilizar el Data Base Tuning Advisor (DETA) con el query que te da problemas. DETA te ofrecerá sugerencias de mejora en la estructura de la base de datos para hacer más eficiente el query (a veces sugiere la creación de índices, estadísticas, etc.).

2.- Otra cosa que puedes hacer es analizar el plan de ejecución y detectar algo intersante como barridos secuenciales (table scan) en lugar de búsquedas con índices (index seek) por ejemplo.

3.- Si quieres algunos consejos muy generales entonces quizá ver estos [consejos sobre uso de índices en SQL Server](http://dbadixit.com/10-consejos-practicos-indices-sql-server/) te sea de utilidad.