# Reporte SSRS tarda en generarse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssrs

Estoy generando reportes de SSRS en un ReportViewer en ASP.NET con VB.NET, no he podido solucionar que la primera vez que se genera el reporte tarda demasiado.¿Como se soluciona esa demora?

Agrego Codigo como cargo el Reporte al ReportViewer:

```
 
Protected Sub GenerarReporte()

        ' Asigna valores de SSRS a ReportViewer

        rvOferta.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://server/ReportServer")

        Select Case fnPedidosLeerDatos(Session("id")).Rows.Item(0)("IdTipo")

            Case 2 To 5

                rvOferta.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reportes/OfertaL"

            Case Else

                rvOferta.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reportes/Oferta"

        End Select

        'Parametros para el reporte SSRS

        Dim parametros As List(Of ReportParameter) = New List(Of ReportParameter)()

        parametros.Add(New ReportParameter("Id", Session("Id").ToString))

        'Envia los parametros para el reporte

        rvOferta.ServerReport.SetParameters(parametros)

        'Actualiza ReportViewer

        rvOferta.ServerReport.Refresh()

        'Muestra Panel q contiene la oferta

        ModalOferta.Show()

End Sub
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Se arregla usando indices lee este artículo: https://programacion.net/articulo/indices_y_optimizacion_de_consultas_305/2

Comment: Aplica para SQL Server??

Comment: Básicamente es la misma lógica pero si quieres ser especifico: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34214/cual-es-la-mejor-pr%C3%A1ctica-para-crear-un-index-en-sql-server https://www.1keydata.com/es/sql/sql-create-index.php https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apinedo/2007/01/24/mejorar-el-rendimiento-de-queries-en-sql-server/

Comment: Básicamente el problema está en la base de datos. Utilizando índices, usando consultas más pequeñas(subconsultas), procedimientos almacenados y minimizando el uso de cursores o tablas temporales, debe mejorar sustancialmente el tiempo de acceso al reporte.

Comment: los datos para el reporte los obtengo con 2 procedimientos almacenados: el primero para los datos generales del reporte y el segundo para el detalle.
siempre la primera vez que se genera el reporte tarda demasiado, si luego lo genero incluso con otra información es mas rápido.