# ¿Consultar valor del úlltimo registro de una tabla hijo para usar como condición?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un reporte de conteo de pedidos que ha entregado cada usuario, tengo un tabla llamada Pedido donde guardo Id_Pedido (y demás información relevante al pedido) y una tabla llamada Radios_Pedidos donde se guarda un historico de asignaciones y entregas de un pedido (según las reglas del negocio un pedido se puede entregar varias veces). He intentado el siguiente código:

```
DECLARE
        @incicio Date = '2018-09-11',
        @fin Date = '2018-09-11'
    SELECT 
        usr.id_usuario as _idUsuario,
        usr.nombre AS _nomUsuario,
        usr.username AS _userName,
        usr.id_rol AS _idRol,
        rol.descripcion AS _descrRol,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(ped.Id_Pedido)
            FROM Pedido AS ped
            WHERE (
                ped.status_pedido = 1 AND 
                ped.Completo = 1 AND 
                ped.Id_Usuario = usr.id_usuario AND 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(radiospedidos.fecha AS datetime) AS fecha
                    FROM Radios_Pedidos AS radiospedidos
                    WHERE (radiospedidos.id_pedido = ped.Id_Pedido AND radiospedidos.tipo = 'ENTREGA')
                    ORDER BY radiospedidos.id_radios DESC
                ) >= @incicio AND
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(radiospedidos.fecha AS datetime) AS fecha
                    FROM Radios_Pedidos AS radiospedidos
                    WHERE (radiospedidos.id_pedido = ped.Id_Pedido AND radiospedidos.tipo = 'ENTREGA')
                    ORDER BY radiospedidos.id_radios DESC
                ) <= @fin
            )
        ) AS totalUsuario
    FROM usuarios AS usr
    JOIN roles AS rol ON usr.id_rol = rol.id_rol
    WHERE (
        usr.isactive = 1
    )
```

Mi problema radica en el subquery denominado totalUsuario, en primer lugar porque todos los registros de usuario, en la propiedad totalUsuario, me devuelve 0, en segundo lugar porque estoy anidando un par de subquerys mas, no creo que eso sea óptimo, y también porque necesito obligatoriamente que el filtro de fecha aplique al ultimo registro de 'ENTREGA' porque en esa tabla también se guardadn registros de tipo 'ASIGNA'.

¿Algún consejo para hacer que mi query funcione y si se puede optimizar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com pude encontrar la solución a mi problema, solo tuve que aplicar unos ajustes.

```
DECLARE
    @inid Date = '2017-01-01',
    @endd Date = '2018-10-09'
SELECT
     [U].[id_usuario] [_idUsuario]
    ,[U].[nombre] [_nomUsuario]
    ,[U].[username] [_userName]
    ,[U].[id_rol] [_idRol]
    ,[RL].[descripcion] [_descrRol]
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT([P].[Id_Pedido])) [_totalUsuario]
FROM [usuarios] [U]
JOIN [Pedido] [P] ON [P].[Id_Usuario] = [U].[id_usuario] AND [P].[status_pedido] = 1 AND [P].[Completo] = 1
JOIN [Radios_Pedidos] [R] ON [R].[Id_Pedido] = [P].[Id_Pedido] AND [R].[tipo] = 'ENTREGA' AND (CONVERT(datetime,[R].[fecha]) BETWEEN @inid AND @endd)
INNER JOIN [roles] [RL] ON [RL].[id_rol] = [U].[id_rol]
WHERE [U].[isactive] = 1
GROUP BY [U].[id_usuario], [U].[nombre], [U].[username], [U].[id_rol], [RL].[descripcion]
```

Añadí las cláusulas de gruop y añadí un Distinct() al conteo dado que cuando existen varias entregas del mismo pedido el conteo me sumaba de dos o mas (según fuera el caso).

Answer (score 1):

Quizá buscas algo como esto

```
SELECT
     [U].[id_usuario] [_idUsuario]
    ,[U].[nombre] [_nomUsuario]
    ,[U].[username] [_userName]
    ,[U].[id_rol] [_idRol]
    ,[RL].[descripcion] [_descrRol]
    ,COUNT([R].[id_pedido]) [totalUsuario]
FROM [Radios_Pedidos] [R]
JOIN [Pedido] [P]
ON [P].[Id_Pedido] = [R].[id_pedido] AND [P].[status_pedido] = 1 AND [P].[Completo] = 1
JOIN [usuarios] [U]
ON [U].[id_usuario] = [P].[Id_Usuario] AND [U].[isactive] = 1
JOIN [roles] [RL] ON [RL].[id_rol] = [U].[id_rol]
WHERE
    [R].[tipo] = 'ENTREGA'
    CONVERT(datetime,[R].[fecha]) BEETWEN @inid AND @endd
```

Por otro lado,

- Trata de normalizar los nombres de las columnas `ON [U].[id_usuario] = [P].[Id_Usuario]` =(
- Guarda cada valor con su tipo definido. Y más aún si necesitas operar con ellos `CONVERT(datetime,[R].[fecha]) BEETWEN @inid AND @endd` =(
- Revisa este hilo de es.estackoverflow.com sobre la creación de índices.

  [¿Cual es la mejor práctica para crear un Index en SQL Server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34214/cual-es-la-mejor-pr%C3%A1ctica-para-crear-un-index-en-sql-server)

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta pude encontrar la solución, por alguna razón el sitio no me dejó añadir tu nombre de usuario para darte crédito, pero gracias!